# psexec multiple command combination

Tags: batch-file, psexec

This is my BAT code, it works but runs in two instances. Anyone know a way to combine these commands to run in only once instance of PSExec?

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%a in ('psexec \\%id% reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer"') do set reg=%%a 

psexec \\%id% reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook"|find /i "x86"
```

Comment: You are leaving out some code. Where does `%id%` come from? You could break it up into smaller sections but there is probably a better way if you show all of the code.

Comment: the %id% is just a prompt to request the entry, pretty straight forward    set /p id="Enter the computer you want to query: "  The issue is with the two PSExec commands i've tried to combine them using &,&&, and ^&  in various ways but PSExec either doesn't run them both or errors out. The code runs fine with them separated but i was just hoping to speed up the process by not having to open two instances of PSExec.

Comment: I have same issue, if you found solution, please share